# Apache stops responding after a while when activating HTTP/2

Tags: apache-2.4, http2

I have apache 2.4.41 on Ubuntu 20.04 and run a certain application through PHP-FPM, with the MPM set to 'event'. Recently, in an attempt to speed up the application, I enabled HTTP/2 in the virtualhost by adding `Protocols h2 http/1.1`. Of course I first checked if the HTTP2 module was enabled using `apachectl -M`. I checked the response from the server: HTTP/2 is working. Apache2 accepts the protocol handshake and the application is noticeably faster.

Now after a few days (or sometimes hours) of use, the application stops responding to requests. When I check `htop`, I don't see high CPU processes or memory usage. Checking the status of apache, php-fpm and mariadb processes doesn't reveal any error either.

I removed the `h2` parameter from the `Protocols` directive and reloaded apache, which solves it. But of course I would like to use HTTP/2. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Which logs I could check to get a clue, or which tests I could perform?

Comment: What does your logs show?

Comment: I assume you are referring to the error log for that specific virtual host. There is nothing in there.